# stacking two UITableViews in a single view programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, subview

i'd like to stack two UITableViews in a single view.  i can do this in interface builder, however, i would like to do this programmatically in code.

in my main UIViewController, i create two UITableViewControllers in my viewDidLoad method.
i thought at first i could do this by:

```
[self.view addSubView:controller1.view];
[self.view addSubView:controller2.view];
```

but this only shows the 2nd view.  i've also tried:

```
[self.view addSubview:controller1.view];
[controller1.view addSubview:controller2.view];
```

but it still doesn't do what interface builder did above.

UPDATE

i want to accomplish this:

[two table views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGnqI.png)

which i did in interface builder:

[xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ePm.png)

but in code.

Comment: your first approach should be correct.  do you have your frames set correctly?  can you show us the look you are going for? also do you need 2 separate controllers?  You should just be able to add the table views themselves directly to your main controller.

Comment: i don't think i have my frames set correctly.  i do need two separate controllers, because i'm using two separate NSFetchedResultsControllers (using this [approach](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)) each tied to two separate controllers acting as UITableViewDataSource delegates.  combining them into one would make it unnecessarily complicated.  i want to accomplish [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IRDwu.png), which was done in [interface builder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ePm.png), but only in code.  how do i set my frames correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the reason to create two UITableViewControllers? Simply create two UITableView objects and manipulate them.

Comment: i have two different NSFetchedResultControllers that are tied to two different UITableViewControllers.  i built them like this: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)- combining them into one UITableViewController would make it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: i decided to take this approach: two UITableViews, one UITableViewController acting as UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.  in my controller, i created two NSFetchedResultsControllers and switch between the two, based on what section was being requested.

Comment: Oh, I was busy and didn't read your comments. So, I glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Overlapped? Did you set their frame different, in order to see them?

Comment: i think you're on the right direction, but i don't know how to go about that.  how do i set their frame different?

Answer (score 0):

```
controller1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,75);
controller2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,75,320,385);
```

In a rectangle the values are measured from the upper left corner: x,y,w,h.

Comment: this is getting closer, but if i provide an absolute height for my first view, then it gets cut off if its longer.  also, when i scroll with my thumb, the first and second views scroll independently.  i want to present them as a single view, one after the other, no matter what height the first view is.

Comment: Oh. You are talking about a grouped table. You want a single table but you need to specify more than one section.